# React-navigation How to put StackNavigator in TabRouter screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having some issue with `react-navigation`. I want to have a custom Tab Bar in which one of the screen is made of a `StackNavigator`.

So Basically, I have

```
Tab
  -- StackNavigator
     -- Dashboard (main)
     -- Wallet
     -- Etc...
  -- Other tabs...
```

To make my custom tab, I used `TabRouter`, `createNavigationContainer` and `createNavigator`

```
const Tabs = TabRouter(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
    tabBarComponent: TabView.TabBarBottom,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    backBehavior: 'none',
  },
);

const CustomTabView = ({ router, navigation }) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
  const ActiveScreen = router.getComponentForState(navigation.state);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ActiveScreen
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          ...navigation,
          state: routes[index],
        })}
      />
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        {routes.map(route => (
          <TouchableOpacity                          // custom tab items
            key={route.routeName}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
          >
            <TabItem />

          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const TabBar = createNavigationContainer(createNavigator(Tabs)(CustomTabView));
```

Where Main is:

```
const Main = StackNavigator({
  Dashboard: Dashboard,
  Wallet: Wallet,
  ...
}, { initialRouteName: 'Dashboard' });
```

But it doesn't because Dashboard must declares a screen.

What I'm doing wrong? I don't know. How can we put a StackNavigator in a TabBar screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, it's very easy.

What `StackNavigator` (or any other navigator) returns is React component. That means you can use it as `screen` component for any other route.

Thus, one of your routes `screen` will be `StackNavigator`.

Sample code

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        Dashboard: {
          screen: Dashboard,
        }
        Wallet: {
          screen: Wallet,
        }
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
    tabBarComponent: TabView.TabBarBottom,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    backBehavior: 'none',
  },
);
```

Comment: It's wasn't working for a while and suddenly, it works. Thanks! However, the stack navigator doesn't have NavBar (header) Do you know what's wrong with my code? Shouldn't the ActiveScreen have the navBar included? Or do I have to manually add one before the ActiveScreen in the CustomTabView?